# Bash: files with accented characters are not processed

Tags: bash

I use this command to split mkv files

```
for f in *.mkv
do
fbname=$(basename "$f" .mkv)
echo "$fbname"
echo "Split raring $fbname"
rar a -v3922480 -m0 "$fbname.rar" "$fbname.mkv"
done
```

but files with accented characters in filenames are not processed, terminal return "no files" error.
For example files with these names are not processed

```
La.Vita.è.bella.mkv
anthonà this morning.mkv
```

is there a solution to fix this ?

Comment: where does your error occur ? can you see the correct file name inside the 2 echo ?

Comment: Works for me with rar implementation from http://www.rarlab.com/rar/rarlinux-x64-5.5.0.tar.gz

Comment: I have locale set to en_US.UTF8, what's yours?

Comment: Same. I just installed rar using `apt install rar` on ubuntu 20.04, and it worked out of the box. Maybe your OS is to blame ?

Comment: yes, I got "No files" when I use C locale, that's probably it

Comment: This question should be moved to https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Comment: Which of your statements produces the error message? In the C-locale, using accented characters looks like undefined behaviour for me. How are the characters encoded in the directory entries?

Comment: @Aserre no, from terminal `Maternità` is written in this way `Maternit'$'\303\240`

Comment: @user1934428 error is this `WARNING: No files`

Comment: "terminal returns" is not helpful. The terminal itself is just a display; it doesn't create errors, it only shows them -- so knowing something shows up on the terminal doesn't tell us which of the several programs you're running (bash itself, or the `basename` program, or the `rar` program) printed it. It matters if it's the _shell_ saying `*.mkv` has no matches, or `rar` saying it can't find the filename passed to it in the current directory, or something else at fault. Consider using `set -x` to enable trace-level logging so you can say more about where in execution this was generated.

Comment: @SuperSonic :..... This does not really answer my two questions. I did not ask about the error message; you alredy wrote it in you post.

Comment: `Maternit'$'\303\240` looks like UTF-8 encoding. Programs processing such directory need to setup the locale accordingly. Otherwise, the `à`` will be understood as two characters (in the C-locale).

Answer (score 0):

Three possibilities that I can think of:

1. the **installed OS** is not UTF-8 compliant;
2. the '**locale**' command does not report settings/values that incorporate UTF-8 (or utf-16/UTF-32); or
3. the installed **version of rar** is not UTF-8 compliant

You might want to review the comments/discussion on **[this](https://superuser.com/questions/1753662/how-can-i-set-my-systems-default-encoding-to-utf-16)** question for other insights into the problem.  Depending on where there is a breakdown, there is no answer/solution at this time.

Comment: Yes, problem is number 2: *the 'locale' command does not report settings/values that incorporate UTF-8* - Ubuntu version is elementary O.S 6.1 Jolnir

Comment: That might be you profile settings or that might be the OS installation.